# Prove that $u_{n} = \frac{1}{n(10n+1)}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, divergent-series

**Question**

> Prove that $u_{n} = \frac{1}{n(10n+1)}$ is convergent

**Attempt**

$u_{n} = \frac{1}{n(10n+1)}$

$u_{n} = \frac{1}{n(10n+1)} = \frac{A}{n}+\frac{b}{10n+1}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{10n+1}$

$S_{n} = u_{1}+u_{2}+u_{3}+...+u_{n-1}+u_{n} =\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{31}+\frac{1}{4}...+\frac{1}{10n+1}-\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{10n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{10n+1}$

S = $ \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac{1}{10n+1})=1 $, thus it is Convergent. But I've messed something up with A,B and I can't figure out what exactly

Comment: Maybe $u_{n} = \frac{1}{n(10n+1)} = \frac{A}{n}+\frac{b}{10n+1}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{10}{10n+1}$?

Comment: It seems you want to prove that $\sum_n u_n$ converges, rather than $\{u_n\}$. Please see my answer and let me know if you have any questions. @lokey8573

Comment: More simply we can use that $\frac{1}{n(10n+1)}=\frac{1}{10n^2+n}\le \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: user thank you very much, you saved me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in your partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{n(10n+1)}$ since $$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{10n+1}=\frac{9n+1}{n(10n+1)}\neq \frac{1}{n(10n+1)}$$ *Hint: Check your value for $b$*

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks if $u_n$ is convergent, instead of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$. Certainly, $u_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$. Regardless, for the sum, consider the following hints. Let $$v_n := \frac{u_n}{10} = \frac{1}{10n(10n+1)}$$
Clearly, $\sum v_n$ converges if and only if $\sum u_n$ converges. For the convergence of $\sum v_n$, the idea is to show that a "bigger" sum converges. Observe that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ converges, and
$$\left\{\frac{1}{10n(10n+1)}: n\in \mathbb N\right\} \subsetneq \left\{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}: n\in \mathbb N\right\}$$
Can you fill in the details?

Answer (score 0):

A simple elementary proof
that bounds the expression
by something that telescopes.

For $n \ge 2$

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1}{n(10n+1)}
&=\dfrac1{10}\dfrac{1}{n(n+\frac1{10})}\\
&\lt\dfrac1{10}\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}\\
&=\dfrac1{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\\
\end{array}\\
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=2}^m\dfrac{1}{n(10n+1)}
&\lt \sum_{n=2}^m\dfrac1{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= \dfrac1{10}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{m}\right)\\
&< \dfrac1{10}\\
\end{array}\\
$